# Zend CSRF hash code check is handled automatically?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have added following code to my login form

```
$csrf = $this->createElement('hash', 'csrf', array('salt' => 'unique'));
```

And in controller action i have

```
if (!$admin_login_form->isValid($_POST)) {
    //Throw Error
}else{
    // Redirect to index
}
```

Now Question is that does Zend handle hash code checking automatically or do we have to code something manually to verify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The answer is no.** You don't have to do anything to check wether the hash is valid or not.

When you create a `Zend_Form_Element_Hash` element, it automatically adds a validator (using `Zend_Validate_Identical`) to your form and register your hash into a new namespace session.

Afterwards, once you call `isValid()` method, if the CSRF stored in the session when the page was rendered is not the same than the one sent in the last request, the Identical validator will fail and return an error.

**Edit:**
Additionally, you can add a salt to your element and a hash will be generate according to the following encryption: `md5(mt_rand(1,1000000) .  $this->getSalt() .  $this->getName() . mt_rand(1,1000000)`.

To answer your second question in your comment, two elements won't cause any session conflicts since the namespace used to store the hash is define by three criteria:

1. The class name
2. The salt
3. The element name

For example, your element would probably be stored under this namespace: "**Zend_Form_Element_Hash_unique_ hash**" where "unique" is the salt value and hash you element name.

Comment: Thank you, Additionally can u please tell me that what is the word "salt" for? And If I have more than one form then would this session conflict?

Comment: Well, since English is not my native language I won't go for a deep definition, but in my opinion a salt is a random string that you can concatenate to a hash/password to make it even more secure. I will answer your second question in my original answer.

Comment: Thank you once again, it seems you are having sound knowledge of zend framework. Have you any reading material or tutorials for Zend beginners? I want to go in depth. Thank you once again.

Comment: I've started using ZF few months ago actually, and honestly I haven't found anything better than the official documentation and Stack Overflow so far... moreover, ZF is a framework that's growing fast, lots of tutorials on internet are quite old.

Comment: i have downloaded so many materials and videos, but instead of getting clear, i get confused after reading. Just to be confirm can u please comment out here the link u are referring for zend framework. Just to be sure only.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/ and http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/ for the API